# How to increase a function speed being calling 400 time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list named `dfs`. It contains 400 `Pandas dataframes` of size `700 rows x 400 columns`.

I have a function like this:

```
def updateDataframe(i):
    global dfs
    df = dfs[i]

    df["abc"].iloc[-1] = "xyz"

    df["abc2"] = df["abc"].rolling(10).mean()

    ........ #More pandas operations like this

    dfs[i] = df



for i in range(len(dfs)):
    updateDataframe(i)
```

Now, this loop takes 10 seconds to execute. I have tried python multi-processing, but it takes same time and somtimes even more.

Things I tried:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp #Multi process Library, used for speeding up download
p=mp.Pool(8) #Define Number of Process to Use
p.map(updateDataframe,range(len(dfs))) # Call the Download Image funciton
p.close() #Close the multi threads
p.join()
```

Also tried this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == "__main__":  # confirms that the code is under main function
    processes = []
    for i in range(len(dfs)):
        process = Process(target=updateDataframe, args=(i,))
        processes.append(process)
        processes.start()

    # complete the processes
    for i in range(len(processes)):
        processes[i].join()
```

Comment: Try to pass object instead of index.

Comment: or could you set a label column with 1 ~ 400 to each dataframe, and concat them together. Then, try separating the `updateDataframe` func step by step to handle the whole dataframe.

Comment: BTW,correct me if I'm wrong,but I seem to remember `numpy` matrixes have a high overhead when it comes to the `=` operator.

Comment: I tried that @OlvinRoght did not increase speed at all

Comment: Will try @Ferris

Comment: @PunitSharma, try to pass copy of object and return updated copy from function.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, how exactly. Can you write a small example code please! @OlvinRoght